# How to show core data when app runs

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am able to successfully show the score details on my Score Table View Controller, however, when I close and reopen the app, the data is no longer there.

I am using the following code in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear in my Score Table View Controller:

```
    // Game Data

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SaveGame")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "datePlayed", ascending: false)]
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    do {
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
    print(fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count)

    scoresTableView.dataSource = self
```

I can successfully display all the “score history” data but NOT until the user exits the app. The Score Table View then just displays empty data.

I have seen CoreData tutorials but using them would made me change my whole code. I would prefer to know some snippet of code to be put on the viewWillAppear for me to be able to persist the data even when user exits the app...

Comment: The `fetchResultsController` is supposed to be created as a lazy instantiated property rather than creating always new instances in `view...`

Comment: @vadian how do you do that?

Comment: Without the all implementation of coredata it is near impossible to tell you where the problem lies, and seing that you don't want to follow the tutorial path i'd say there is a good chance something is not implemented correctly, please provide proper code.

Comment: Create a new Master-Detail sample project in Xcode with Core Data enabled and look at the automatically created code.

Comment: Try `scoresTableView.reloadData()`.